# Rails ActiveAdmin has_one and belongs_to causes 'Undefined Method for <PLURAL_RESOURCE>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin

In Rails, I have a 'User' model and a 'Wallet' model. A 'User' has_one wallet and each 'Wallet' belongs_to a 'User'. I made a 'Show' page in ActiveAdmin to view a User's Wallet. However, going to that page returns this error:

```
undefined method `wallets' for #<User:0x007f...>
```

HOWEVER, when I update the User model to 'has_many :wallets' instead of ':has_one wallet', everything works. Here is the relevant code from my models and ActiveAdmin code:

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :wallet, dependent: :destroy
end


class Wallet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

ActiveAdmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Wallet do
  belongs_to :user
  actions :all, except: :destroy

  show do
    div do
      'hello'
    end
  end
end

ActiveAdmin.register User do
  actions :all, except: :destroy
  permit_params

  action_item :wallet, only: :show do
    link_to('Wallet', admin_user_wallet_path(user, user.wallet.id))
  end

  index do...
end
```

Any ideas as to where I might have gone wrong?

**Edit 1:** updates to correct colon placement mistakes in description

**Edit 2:**

in response to:

> Can you show your routes file? Also, can you give us the full traceback of the error message and give us the output of rake routes? I suspect that the reason it's complaining about wallets not being defined (even though you never call wallets in the above code) is that some routing is making assumptions about how the relationships look. – Glyoko 4 mins ago

1. My routes file contains no mention 'wallet' or 'wallets'.
2. My stack error more specifically looks like this:

   activemodel (4.1.15) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb, line 435

   Let me know if you need more than that.
3. Here's the related output from 'bin/rake routes':

   - admin_user_wallets GET      /admin/users/:user_id/wallets(.:format)                        admin/wallets#index
   - POST     /admin/users/:user_id/wallets(.:format)                        admin/wallets#create
   - new_admin_user_wallet GET     /admin/users/:user_id/wallets/new(.:format)                 admin/wallets#new
   - edit_admin_user_wallet GET       /admin/users/:user_id/wallets/:id/edit(.:format)               admin/wallets#edit
   - admin_user_wallet GET
     /admin/users/:user_id/wallets/:id(.:format)                    admin/wallets#show
   - admin_user_wallet PATCH  /admin/users/:user_id/wallets/:id(.:format)                    admin/wallets#update
   - admin_user_wallet PUT /admin/users/:user_id/wallets/:id(.:format)                    admin/wallets#update

Comment: Can you show your routes file? Also, can you give us the full traceback of the error message and give us the output of `rake routes`? I suspect that the reason it's complaining about `wallets` not being defined (even though you never call `wallets` in the above code) is that some routing is making assumptions about how the relationships look.

Comment: Edited to address this comment^^

Comment: Can you give the _full_ backtrace for #2 (app and framework)? I expect it to be like 50 lines. And are there any calls in routes.rb to ActiveAdmin methods? If the answer below works then maybe this isn't necessary, but I might be able to give a better answer

Answer (score 4):

`ActiveAdmin` uses `InheritedResources` gem internally, the `belongs_to` method ends up inside `InheritedResources`.

Possible solution here

```
ActiveAdmin.register Wallet do
  belongs_to :user, singleton: true
  actions :all, except: :destroy
end
```

The option `singleton: true` makes the `Wallet` a singular resource for the `User`.

Probably, another option `optional: true` may be helpful if Wallet is not required for any `User` to present

Answer (score 0):

Even though your routes may not explicitly reference `wallet(s)`, there may be something there making assumptions about how records are related to each other.

Look at the output of `rake routes`, in particular:

```
admin_user_wallet GET
/admin/users/:user_id/wallets/:id(.:format) admin/wallets#show
```

When you call `admin_user_wallet_path(user, user.wallet.id)` it's matching the `/admin/users/:user_id/wallets/:id(.:format)` route. Notice how that expects both a user id and a wallet id in the path. This is a tip-off that something is off here, since if you have the user, there should be exactly one wallet associated with it. You shouldn't *need* to give both the user and wallet id.

Since the wallet resource is nested under users, the page where you view the user's wallet is actually more of an index page than a show. If the wallet were an independent resource, then you could have a path like `/admin/wallets/:id` and things would work out fine.

But since the wallet is a *subresource* of the user, you would ideally want a path like `/admin/users/:user_id/wallet`. There's no need to pass the wallet id, since you already have the user.

---

tl;dr: Try changing the `show`s to `index`s and see where that gets you. e.g.

```
index do
  div do
    'hello'
  end
end

# ...

action_item :wallet, only: :index do
  link_to('Wallet', admin_user_wallets_path(user))
end
```

Comment: This is actually a slight simplification of what's happening. I'm not too familiar with ActiveAdmin, but it seems like something is assuming (perhaps in the framework, perhaps in your configuration?) that the nested resource is pluralistic. In pure rails, there is a way to have nested singular resources, but something seems to be precluding that here.

This is a relatively clean workaround however, and is probably acceptable for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. So I had this same exact issue. I had a belongs_to a parent where the parent had only a has_one to the child model..... Nothing seemed to work so I decided to fake it. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this but it worked. In the parent model, add a method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :wallet
   def wallets
     Wallet.where(user_id: id)
    end
  end
```

The above code is a hotfix until I can find some other way to implement what I need.

Comment: Don't fake it, `single: true` is the answer